# What is the smallest class of reductions under which there is a $\mathsf{P}$-complete problem?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

It is common to define $P$-completeness with respect to log-space many-one reductions.

I am looking for a complexity class $C \subseteq \mathsf{L}$ such that 
there are $\mathsf{P}$-complete problems w.r.t. many-one $C$-reductions.

> What is the smallest known many-one reduction class $C$ 
>   such that HornSAT is complete for $\mathsf{P}$ under $C$-reductions?

The question was originally posted on [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37562/weakest-reduction-for-p-completeness) with no answer.

Comment: Maybe you mean all non-trivial problems: the empty language and the language whose complement is empty cannot be complete.

Comment: @SashoNikolov  Sure, I am not interested in trivial languages!

Comment: I don't understand the question. If C=P then all problems in P except the trivial ones are complete for P under C-reductions, and this is the case independent of what C is.

Comment: @Kaveh What is the smallest such class $C$? For instance, is HornSAT complete for $P$ under $NC^1$ Reductions?

Comment: Edited post to remove confusion.

Comment: I share Kaveh’s confusion about the first paragraph. But concerning the blue question, a reasonable encoding of Horn-SAT is P-complete under DLOGTIME reductions.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I edited the paragraph to address your and others comments. I am looking for reductions weaker than $L$ such as $NC^1$.

Comment: As Email wrote. I don't know any natural P-complete problem which is not complete under AC0 reductions and one can go to even weaker reductions I think. Since reductions between complete problems can typically be computed in AC0, as soon as we have a complete problem under AC0 (e.g. CircuitValue) all of them become complete under AC0 reductions.

Comment: @Kaveh Do you have a reference for AC0 reductions? Please convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: I don't have a reference off my head.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easy to show that the *Circuit Value Problem* is complete for $\mathsf{P}$ 
under $\mathsf{AC^0}$ reductions (see  András's comment below).

For an easier example consider 
$$A = \{\langle M,x,y\rangle \mid \text{$M$ accepts $x$ in $|y|$ steps} \}$$

If a class of reductions $C$ contains constant functions, pairing of strings, and functions where the size of their output can bound any polynomial;
then $A$ is complete for $\mathsf{P}$ w.r.t. $C$.

Comment: For P-completeness of CVP under FO-reductions, see Exercise 3.28 in Immerman's _Descriptive Complexity_.